# How to add user images on a world globe?

Tags: html5

I need a user images on world globe like this [design](https://prnt.sc/GkjZ7_cxMw1m).

I already use this [code](https://codepen.io/bartuc/pen/yMMyav) but can't able to add user images here. Is there any way to add images on this globe or any one have code similar to my [design](https://prnt.sc/GkjZ7_cxMw1m). Any suggestions?

Comment: It looks like it's a WebGL scene using three.js, so I guess you just need to float the user images as sprites in space above the correct coordinates on the globe? I don't know three.js but I assume that's straightforward. https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/objects/Sprite

Comment: What's the WordPress angle here? You're getting the user images from get_avatar_url and you're storing their lat & long coordinates in user meta somehow?